# Importing fxcontrols jar file into eclipse doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, import, controlsfx

I wanted to try the fxcontrols' SpreadsheetView example code at:

https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html

Somehow, adding their .jar file to my Eclipse test project as an external jar file doesn't help me resolve the import statements that are necessary. For instance, it doesn't resolve/find the GridBase, SpreadSheetCell, or SpreadsheetView. Trying to manually import org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView doesn't work either.

Shouldn't this just work immediately? I feel like the biggest noob right now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out fxcontrols is broken and I should be using fxcontrols 8 along with jdk 1.8.